# Como ler arquivo .csv e usar como lista em Python

Tags: python, lista

Estou precisando que o Python leia um arquivo CSV e use os dados nele como uma lista.

exemplo de dados do CSV

```
francisco,
carlos,
melo,
luis,
claudia,
```

e preciso que após a leitura o Python use esses dados como essa lista abaixo:

```
lista = (['francisco','carlos','melo','luis','claudia'])
```

Esbarrei em situações que ele emitia linha por linha ou tinha uma quebra de linha `\n` atrapalhando ou a vírgula acabava dentro da aspa simples: 'francisco,'.
........................................................................

Pessoal depois de hoooooras quebrando a cabeça conseguir o que queria. Como estou iniciando os detalhes acabam se tornando coisas grandes.

Fiz assim e deu certo para mim:

```
arq_listas = open('C:/...arq_listas.csv', 'r')
lista = arq_listas.read().split(',\n')
arq_listas.close()
```

o resultado que tive foi:

```
lista = (['francisco','carlos','melo','luis','claudia',''])
```

obrigado pela atenção de todos.

Comment: Se esbarrou em algo, significa que tentou, então adicione o seu código à pergunta e descreva o resultado obtido. Aliás, o formato que apresentou não é exatamente um CSV, mas sim várias linhas que terminam com uma vírgula. No CSV, isso representaria vários registros de duas colunas, sendo que a segunda coluna sempre é nula. Não parece isso que você quer.

Comment: Já conseguiste resolver o problema?

Comment: Anderson e Miguel, consegui resolver o problema. Editei a minha pergunta incluindo a solução que foi viável para mim. Obrigado pela atenção.